# Doxygen with Visual C++ unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, doxygen

I am trying to document some VC++ unit test classes with doxygen.  Due to the macro-formed classes and methods, doxygen is unable to detect a class or method declaration, at least by default.

Is there any way of giving doxygen a way of detecting a declaration unconventional to the given language?  If not, can I somehow manually introduce links into the dox so that I can still cross-reference the test classes/methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doxygen can expand macros, set `MACRO_EXPANSION` to `YES` in the doxygen configuration. Doxygen will then expand all macros. You can additionally set `EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF` to `YES` and pass a list of macros that doxygen should expand using `PREDEFINED` or `EXPAND_AS_DEFINED`.

See here for more information: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html

Answer (score 0):

In the doxygen configuration file there is a tag called [MACRO_EXPANSION](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_macro_expansion). You can try setting that to YES, which should allow doxygen to detect the macro definitions.

Comment: Not sure this is going to do much for me.  These macros are function macros from the VC++ unit testing framework, and I'm not sure I want doxygen to preprocess all that.  Thanks, though.

Comment: You can provide custom definitions of the macros for Doxygen by using the PREDEFINED option. Or you can provide custom Doxygen file where you put the definitions of the macros - for example a *.dox file and add *.dox to the FILE_PATTERNS.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, enabling MACRO_EXPANSION does not work with the CppUnitTest framework. But, replacing the macro manually as such:

```
class YourClassName: public TestClass<YourClassName>
```

does have effect.